# Add a legend for multiple geom_vline in facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-vline

I am trying to add a legend for multiple `geom_vlines` in a `facet_wrap`, but I can't manage to keep the colors in the graphs.
I have added `aes` on each `vline`, but they appear grey.

```
ggp +
  geom_vline (aes(xintercept = median(overall_vector), color = "red"), linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_vline (aes(xintercept = quantile(overall_vector,0.80), color = "green"), linetype = "dashed") + 
  geom_vline (aes(xintercept = quantile(overall_vector,0.20), col = "orange"), linetype = "dashed") +
  scale_color_manual(name = "statistics", values = c(median = "red", "p 80" = "green", "p 20" = "orange"))
```

[image: What I see]

If I take out the `aes` it just doesn't show the legend. It happens the same if I keep `aes` on only the median `vline`

```
ggp +
  geom_vline (xintercept = median(overall_vector), color = "red", linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_vline (xintercept = quantile(overall_vector,0.80), color = "green", linetype = "dashed") + 
  geom_vline (xintercept = quantile(overall_vector,0.20), col = "orange", linetype = "dashed") +
  scale_color_manual(name = "statistics", values = c(median = "red", "p 80" = "green", "p 20" = "orange"))
```

[image: Example 2]

The legend only shows if I add `aes` to at least 1 `vline`, but that `vline` becomes grey.

```
ggp +
  geom_vline (xintercept = median(overall_vector), color = "red", linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_vline (xintercept = quantile(overall_vector,0.80), color = "green", linetype = "dashed") + 
  geom_vline (aes(xintercept = quantile(overall_vector,0.20), col = "orange"), linetype = "dashed") +
  scale_color_manual(name = "statistics", values = c(median = "red", "p 80" = "green", "p 20" = "orange"))
```

[image: Example 3]

Thank you!

Comment: With your first approach use `aes(..., color = "median")` for the median vline and so on, i.e. use the labels not the colors